# Which test shall I apply?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Can you kindly help me with my scholarly article?

I observed whether (and to what extent) the 52 SAME companies use their capacities across the years 2006, 2010, 2014, 2018.

Here are the counts of companies (categorized by the extent of usage):

```
2006: none(35) partial(15) full(2)  (=52 total)
2010: none(36) partial(11) full(5)  (=52 total)
2014: none(26) partial(5)  full(21  (=52 total)
2018: none(17) partial(3)  full(32) (=52 total)
```

(Explanation: In 2006, 35 companies did not use their capacities, 15 companies used their capacities only partially, and 2 companies used their capacities fully etc.
BUT: In 2010, observing the SAME COMPANIES as in the year 2006, 36 companies did not use their capacities, 11 companies used them only partially and  5 companies used them fully)

I want to ascertain whether the usage ACROSS the years has (significantly) changed.

Questions:

1) What statistical test shall I apply?
    (categorical variables, paired samples; I tried Friedman test but it produces absurd results)

2) Can you please kindly give me a CONCRETE result for this test? (this is extremely important for me because I need to be sure that I understand the things properly)

Comment: Although I have edited this a little, I have to guess what it is asking.  As both variables are ordered, something more like a Jonckheere-Terpstra test may be suitable. We can't comment on what appeared to go wrong with a Friedman test as you don't show results and don't explain what seemed to you to be absurd.  Find a good text on non-parametric statistics! (I can't see any pairing here.)

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your comment. Please see the additional explanation in the first post..

Comment: Friedman give me p-values: 0,1738, which means there is no difference across the years. But, it is obvious nonsense (because full usage has increased very much evidently)

Comment: How about a Chi-Square Test for Homogeneity between the first and the last year? Would allow you to test of some sort of process was happening in the period.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked your Friedman test result. It doesn't seem to me a good test here if only because the ordering information in the data is not fully considered. A chi-square test comparing first and last years only is even less suitable as ignoring some of the data and all ordering.

More generally and more crucially, a suitable test will have to be based on the 52 trajectories. The samples are not independent.

As you're convinced that there is a pattern, and dismiss any indications to the contrary, I have to wonder why significance testing is a concern here. In what sense your data are a sample from a larger population should be considered.

All you need here for most scholarly purposes is a graph, which can be a table too, e.g.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Many thanks for your information. I will check out and get back soon. Many thanks again

Comment: Hello, many thanks again - I appreciate this. Please note that I am not a mathematician. But, although the difference is obvious, I need to prove it exactly (by a test). I also do not know whether the data is ordered. I just know what I want to ascertain. In order to make the things clearer, I have made a graph.

Comment: Here is the link for the graph:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1l_qRSHiQx9a3LZAkQZDJo-og8XgXAaJ1


black:no usage;  

grey:partial usage;  

white:full usage

In fact, I need to compare 3 proportions and to determin exactly whether they are accross the years statistically different or not.
Can you please help? Many thanks.

Comment: I do not know whether the values are ordered. I only know the question:
Has the FULL usage (white bar) really increased in the course of the time? I need to prove it exactly. Many thanks.

Comment: Very important: The 52 company are - across the years - always the same. This means that it will be a MATCHED (correlated) test. An extension of McNemar (but NOT Bowker test because Bowker applies to a situation where only 2 years are compared - but we compare 4 years)

Comment: Excellent point. The frequencies alone are not the whole information as it leaves out which firms changed, etc.  So, the J-T test is compromised  The ordering is easy: none, partial, full is an order; 2006, ..., 2018 is an order.